# Force Mathematica to do numerical computations with finite precision

Tags: precision, numeric

I would like to analyse the numerical stability of analytic expressions in Mathematica. To this end I want to force Mathematica evaluate the expression numerically at finite precision and compare to a result at much higher precision. The problem is that I do not really get it to forget about extra digits it keeps in the background even if I tell it to do so explicitly. Where is the bug in the following?

```
In[466]:= Sin[2.0]
Out[466]= 0.9092974268256817

In[467]:= Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 0}, N[Sin[2.0], 2]]
Out[467]= 0.9092974268256817

In[468]:= Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 0}, N[Sin[2.0`2], 2]]
Out[468]= 0.91

In[469]:= SetPrecision[%, 16]
Out[469]= 0.9092974268256817
```

Even in the third version it keeps many more digits in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **NumberForm** is what you need.

> NumberForm[expr, n]  prints with approximate real numbers in expr
>   given to n-digit precision.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html

Comment: As I understand, this reduces only the number of digits used for output and not the numerical computation itself. From the Help page you linked: "NumberForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation."